# Filling VBA userform's combobox with table column plus an additional option

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am developing an application, in excel with VBA forms. in one form I have a combobox to that let user select customer name, the rowsource of this combobox is a named range (name column of customers table). Everything working fine but I need to add 1 or more additional items in the combobox that not exist in the table column. For example I need to add "All" item in the cobmobox so user can select a particular customer name or All. at other place I wan't to add "Other" item in combobox with same rowsource so if the customer is new user can select Other and then type name in textbox.

I tried following code to add an item

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
With Me.testCombo
.AddItem "All"
End With
End Sub
```

but i got error 
Run-time error '70'
permission denied

if i remove rowsource property from the combobox then the above code work but only one item "All" display.

Note: I don't want to add "All" and "Other" in customer table, this could be easy solution but will cause other problem.

Comment: You can't add additional items when the `RowSource` property is set. Unset the `RowSource`; add the items into the combo from the range one-by-one in `UserForm_Initialize` then you can add whatever other options.

Comment: Besides how to mark this solved? I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim rowValue        As Variant
    Dim lngCount        As Long
    Dim myCell          As Range
    Dim varCombo()      As Variant

    With Me.ComboBox1

        ReDim varCombo(Me.ComboBox1.ListCount)          

        For Each myCell In Range(.RowSource)
            varCombo(lngCount) = myCell.value
            lngCount = lngCount + 1
        Next myCell

        .RowSource = ""

        For lngCount = LBound(varCombo) To UBound(varCombo) - 1
            .AddItem CStr(varCombo(lngCount))
        Next lngCount

        .AddItem "All"
        .AddItem "Nothing"

    End With

End Sub
```

As mentioned in the comments, by A.S.H., you should unset the .RowSource property. However, you do not lose it, if you run the code twice, it would be the same. In my code I use `UBound(varCombo) - 1`, because I use `lngCount=lngCount+1` on the last looping over the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could do what you need

```
Dim a() As Variant
Dim b() As String
Dim s As String

a = Application.Transpose(Range("a1:a5").Value)
s = "Please select;" & Join(a, ";")
Erase a
b = Split(s, ";")

Me.ComboBox1.List = b
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for helping, the main problem was permission as A.S.H said if Rowsource is set then cannot add any item in the ComboBox. So I delete the RowSource from the properties in form. and wrote following code and it seems everything working fine. I hope my codes are good enough and simple.

```
Private Sub fillComboBox()
        Dim comboData As Range

        With Me.CWR_CustName
            ' first option of comobobox will be All
            .AddItem "All"

            For RW_Cust = 1 To Range("tblCust").Rows.Count

                ' add each customer name from customer table name column
                .AddItem (Range("tblCust[Name]")(RW_Cust))

            Next RW_Cust

        End With
End Sub
```